# Where can I find netflix.exe?

Tags: windows-10, links, netflix

That might sound a bit stupid but I can't get my head around on where `netflix.exe` is actually located. I can see in my process manager that such a process actually exists when I open the app in Windows 10. The problem comes when I actually try to locate it.

I did some research, in previous versions was located in the `C:\Program files\WindowsApp` folder also tried in `C:\Users\username\AppData\Roamming\Windows\Start Menu` but no luck.

See [reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/Rainmeter/comments/7oqo9e/hello_guys_where_is_the_netflixs_win10_app_exe/) for further information.

I don't understand how I can see an exe in my process manager if such a file does not exist.

Comment: You can't find it because it is an app and Microsoft tries to shield users from accessing the files associated with apps.

Comment: What @LPChip is attempting to indicate is that the Netflix application is a Universal Windows Program (UWP) application.  UWP application executables are stored in a directory that by default no user has permissions to view (i.e. WindowsApp).  **Netflix does not have desktop Win32 application.**  Why are you trying to locate the application?  If you no longer want the Netflix UWP application you should simply uninstall it.

Comment: @Ramhound I'm aware windowsapp folder access is not allowed by default to users. In fact I had to allow it to myself to have a look. As I said in the question netflix.exe is not there. The reason I'm trying to locate it is to put an exception rule to a vpn so Netflix does not use. I need to locate that exe.

Comment: UWP applications do not have .exe files.  Only Win32 executables use that file extension

Comment: @Ramhound that's not true actually. UWP apps can have exe files, but they can also have multiple folders. For example, For Microsoft's YourPhone app, I have multiple folders, and one has the exe file, where another one has not. The fact that OP sees the process with .exe extension in the taskbar suggests Netflix has the exe stored somewhere in the UWP folder.

Answer (score 4):

PowerShell is a very powerful tool and can do pretty much anything with any Microsoft product, including UWP Apps.

To [find where an appx is installed](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20171120-00/?p=97425) you can use the command `Get-AppxPackage -Name PackageName`.

The package names are usually very hard to guess, for example the current name of the Netflix app is "4DF9E0F8.Netflix". Some app names have 0 relation to the name shown in the start menu.

To make it a bit easier, you can use the `Where-Object` instead of the `-Name` parameter.

```
Get-AppxPackage | Where-Object {$_.Name -like "*flix*"}
```

This will look for any appx packages which name matches ***flix***.

The result on my computer is this:

```
Name              : 4DF9E0F8.Netflix
Publisher         : CN=52120C15-ACFA-47FC-A7E3-4974DBA79445
Architecture      : X64
ResourceId        :
Version           : 6.93.478.0
PackageFullName   : 4DF9E0F8.Netflix_6.93.478.0_x64__mcm4njqhnhss8
InstallLocation   : C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\4DF9E0F8.Netflix_6.93.478.0_x64__mcm4njqhnhss8
IsFramework       : False
PackageFamilyName : 4DF9E0F8.Netflix_mcm4njqhnhss8
PublisherId       : mcm4njqhnhss8
IsResourcePackage : False
IsBundle          : False
IsDevelopmentMode : False
NonRemovable      : False
IsPartiallyStaged : False
SignatureKind     : Store
Status            : Ok
```

In the `C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\4DF9E0F8.Netflix_6.93.478.0_x64__mcm4njqhnhss8` folder I can see that it's a WinJS app written in HTML, CSS and JavaScript.

## There's no Netflix.exe in that folder?

There's not. **I don't think you've ever seen a Netflix.exe** (unless it's a virus). Here's a screenshot from my Task Manager while having Netflix up and running.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You need to add `C:\Windows\System32\WWAHost.exe` to your VPN exception list. Because Netflix is a UWP app thus `WWAHost.exe` is used for networking.

**Note**: Any apps that use `WWAHost.exe` will be affected as well.

Answer (score 0):

I would tried adding WWAHost.exe (and maybe mfpmp.exe) to your VPN exception list. Those are the 2 .exe programs that are running when netflix opens (other than RuntimeBroker.exe).

mfpmp.exe does not stay open. But WWAHost.exe and RuntimeBroker.exe does.

Worth a shot if your VPN does not support adding Windows Apps.

Answer (score 0):

I have successfully negated Netflix through split tunnelling in Express VPN by taking out this:

```
"C:\Windows\System32\mfpmp.exe"
```

This is listed as Media Foundation Protected Pipeline EXE within task manager.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1144400)